# Meteor iron-router splash screen error on deploy only

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

I'm using Meteor 1.0.3.1 on my local machine, and I'm deploying with node v0.10.36. However, the deploy machine only ever displays the iron-router splash screen... "iron:router" "Organize your Meteor application" ...

There are several other stacks about fixing this exact problem, including removing the  tag and removing the projects npm.js file (left over from bootstrap). None of these are working.

project.js file is as follows:

```
Router.route('/', function () {
  this.render('home');
});

Router.route('/about', function () {
  this.render('about');
});

Router.route('/contact', function () {
  this.render('contact');
});

Router.route('/legal', function () {
  this.render('legal');
});

Router.route('imitationgamereview', function () {
  this.render('imitationgamereview');
});


if (Meteor.isClient) {
}

if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.startup(function () {
    // code to run on server at startup
  });
}
```

project.html file is as follows:

```html
<head>
    <title>my sample project</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico?v=2" />
</head>

<template name="home">
  test
</template>
```

Totally going bonkers! WTF iron-router? I'm so in love with you, then you do stuff to me like this!

Comment: Someone on my team at work was seeing this for a self-deployed (mup-deployed) application. Only *one* of four people *hitting the same app* saw it, and *only with the Google chrome browser*. It went away after he rebooted. :(

Comment: Sadly, that doesn't work here :(

Comment: This tutorial may help you to get started http://kukuruku.co/hub/javascript/meteor-how-to-build-a-todo-list

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps it has to do with the file location of your routing file (project.js). Moving the it to `/lib` solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same splash screen on x.meteor.com and --production emulation until i made sure that every

```
Meteor.publish({});
```

is in an if(Meteor.isServer) statement e.g.

```
if(Meteor.isServer) {
    Meteor.publish('files', function() {
        return Files.find();
    });
}
```

This fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

I've just had a similar problem, and i don't know if this applies to you, but in my case it was the fact that i had two templates (two HTML files) with the same template name. Once i removed one of them, all came back to normal.
I.e., i had this line in both file1.html and file2.html :

```
<template name="sampleList">
```

Nothing really indicated where the problem lied.